# How to display fetched array of objects and save multiple fetched arrays to state?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

If i try to display `user.meniu.pret` inside the map function it wont display anything. `user.meniu[0].pret` displays values but wont give me the final results i want

How can i fetch the data and display the values inside the response.menu ?

```
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const [meniu, setMeniu] = useState()

  const getApiData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://vercelfastfoodapi.vercel.app/fastfood/"
    ).then((response) => response.json());

    setUsers(response);

    setMeniu(response[1].meniu)  // <----------- SAVES VALUES
    setMeniu(response.meniu) // <------------ UNDEFINED

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getApiData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">

 {users &&
        users.map((user) => (
          <div className="item-container" key={user._id}>
            Id: <b> {user.restaurant} </b>  <br/>
            Restaurant: {user.meniu.pret} // <------- WONT DISPLAY ANYTHING. user.meniu[0].pret works fine

          </div>
        ))} 


          <button onClick={() => console.log(meniu)}>aaaa </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Probably `response` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.meniu` is an array not an object. This is the reason why `user.meniu.pret` gives you *undefined* while `user.meniu[0].pret` lets you access the property `pret` of the first object of the array `user.meniu`.
Now, if you want to save all the fetched *menius* in the state you can do:

```
setMeniu(response.map(r => r.meniu)); // remember that the meniu state now will be an array of objects
```

Now, if you want to display all the *pret* values from each object of the array you can simply do:

```
<div className="item-container" key={user._id}>
 Id: <b> {user.restaurant} </b>  <br/>
 Restaurant: {meniu.map(m => m.priet)}
</div>
```

Or if you want to use the *user* object you can do:

```
<div className="item-container" key={user._id}>
 Id: <b> {user.restaurant} </b>  <br/>
 Restaurant: {user.meniu.map(m => m.priet)}
</div>
```